Error docker container nextjs app "Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'" pnpm
I'm developing an app, and the frontend was initially done only with react, and the Docker container worked fine. I wanted to use Next js for the frontend now (I started the clear app from scratch) but I get the following error when trying to make the container for it in docker:
=> ERROR [frontend 7/7] RUN pnpm build 8.6s ------ > [frontend 7/7] RUN pnpm build: 6.638 6.638 > frontend-artesanias@0.1.0 build /app 6.638 > next build 6.638 6.738 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1228 6.738 throw err;
6.738 ^
6.738
6.738 Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
6.738 at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
6.738 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
6.738 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
6.738 at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
6.738 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
6.738 requiresStack: []
6.738 }
6.738
6.738 Node.js v20.18.0
6.747 The ELIFECYCLE command failed with exit code 1.
------
Failed to resolve: Process "/bin/sh -c pnpm build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Here is the frontend Dockerfile:
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app RUN npm install -g pnpm 
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./ 
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile 
COPY . .

RUN pnpm build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]

Here is the docker-compose.yml:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - backend

package.json:
{
  "name": "frontend-artesanias",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "next": "14.2.15",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.15",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

I see the logs of the docker container, and according to what I see, the dependencies are installed, but it does not find the next module (Locally it does work for me), I have already looked at solutions such as removing the volumes that may be being overwritten but I have not been able to solve it, I would appreciate it if anyone knows.

Please read this document first: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying#docker-image
